# Add list of items to PayPal Standard button for payment

Tags: paypal

Feels like it should be possible to create an order with multiple items using standard buttons generated on the Paypal site. Clearly I'm missing something and would appreciate any assistance or information. Below is my page source code and the error message received when pressing the Pay button.

```html
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <!-- Include the PayPal JavaScript SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD&debug..."></script>
    <script>
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({
    style: {
    color: 'blue',
    shape: 'rect',
    label: 'pay',
    },
    
    // Sets up the transaction when a payment button is clicked
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "payer": {
    "name": {
      "given_name": "John",
      "surname": "Doe"
    },
    "address": {
      "address_line_1": "123 nowhere lane",
      "address_line_2": "Apt 2",
      "admin_area_2": "Sacramento",
      "admin_area_1": "CA",
      "postal_code": "93423",
      "country_code": "US"
    },
    "email_address": "sb_test_email_address@business.example.com",
    "phone": {
      "phone_type": "MOBILE",
      "phone_number": {
        "national_number": "12312342343"
      }
    }
  },
  "purchase_units": [
    {
      "description": "My Purchases",
      "amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "12.00",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "12.00"
          },
          "shipping": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "0"
          },
          "tax_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "0"
          }
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 1",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "6.00"
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "6.00"
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
    },
    
    // Finalize the transaction after payer approval
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
    window.location.href = "Thanks.html";
    });
    },
    
    onCancel: function(data) {
    //payment cancelled
    alert("Payment Cancelled");
    },
    
    onError: function(err) {
    alert("Error Message: " + err);
    }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
    </div>

The error message I get is shown in this image. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD8kw.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reformatting the Orders create request payload in your question for legibility and testing just the payload [at the demo site](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client), it worked without issue (screenshot below).

You can also find a reference example in step 6 of 'Add and modify the code' in [the current documentation.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/#add-and-modify-the-code)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation and documentation links. Also for taking the time to straighten up the code and responding with a tested example. I have it working now and marked your response as solution. Much appreciation! Cheers

Comment: In the documentation, they indicate it's possible to get the Total value from a form input box like this. `"value": document.getElementById("txtTotal").value,` That works great for me, if possible I'd like to include Items in a similar way. `"items": [ document.getElementById("txtItems").value ]` doesn't seem to work. Again much appreciated for any guidance.

Comment: You need to build a full items array, not just put a loose value in the array.  Step 6 of "add and modify the code" (linked above) has a full example of what an items array looks like. In particular you need to give an object with a name key, value key, and quantity.

Comment: Separately, when including an items array, don't forget to also add a breakdown object in the amount. It's required

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'll dig into your suggest Step 6 example.

Comment: Oh, this question does have an items array. So basically you need:  `"items": [
        {
          "name": "Item 1",
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": document.getElementById("txtItems").value
          },
          "quantity": "1"
        },` , or whatever function call returns the correct amount for the item, as well as calls for other parameters' values if they are also in the DOM.

Comment: typically your own function is used, e.g. `"items:" getCartItems()`, where that function builds and returns an array with all item objects and values set.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes, I'm just trying to build the items array you provided in the example above dynamically. Sounds like I need to do that using a function as you suggested instead of stuffing a pre-build array into an input or textarea box and just get its value. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Preston, Thanks to your help, this is all working and in the final stages of testing. I've searched all the documentation but can't find anything on Auto-Log Out the customer after payment is complete. Is that possible?

Comment: No, logging out of PayPal is up to payers. They should only be using PayPal on their own devices they have control over.

Comment: Thanks again for sharing your expertise. Can I create a REST App for a Business Acct User instead of the Main acct? Or send the PayPal receipts to an User Acct email instead of Main email? I've tried this but not having any luck and not sure it's possible.

Comment: If there are multiple business owner email addresses (separate from users) that are **confirmed** within the account... https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email , then, setting the checkout transaction's `payee` https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/pay-another-account/ might direct notifications to that particular confirmed email automatically. I haven't tested whether it makes a difference.

Comment: In general if you want some guarantee of notification behavior ... then you should be sending your own notifications, from your own server.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll look into the confirmed business users and payee links you sent. Yes, I'm send notifications from my server.